# MySQL Workbench reading out a BLOB containing a date

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with questions in them. They have a date column with as type a BLOB.

Is it possible for MySQL to read out the BLOB as I can't convert it to a normal DATE type

Comment: MySQL can certainly read the BLOB. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I need to be able to get the date in SQL when a query is used. It will return as BLOB in the field but I need it to return a DATE.

Comment: Why are you storing a date in a BLOB field? Can you update the question to show some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing why you have a DATE stored in a BLOB field have you tried using the [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function?

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(your_blob_field,'%d,%m,%Y');
```